# laravel Goutte filter some of <td> text is return right result while some is return nothing

Tags: laravel, goutte

Hi i am using laravel Goutte package to crawl some specific data for data analysis in my project while i am applying the filter some of td is return the right result while some is not return result anyone have the idea please help my controller code is

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Goutte;
use Goutte\Client;
 use App\Http\Requests;
class MapController1 extends Controller
{
    //
  public function index()
   {

   $crawler = Goutte::request('GET', 'http://www.upsldc.org/real-time-data');
    $crawler->filter('body')->each(function ($node) {
      echo "<pre>";
      //var_dump($node->text());
      echo $node->filter('td')->eq(0)->text();
       echo $node->filter('td.up_schedule')->text();
       echo $node->filter('td')->eq(2)->text();

    });


   }
}
```

it is return **Schedule (MW)Drawl (MW)** but this echo $node->filter('td.up_schedule')->text(); row is return nothing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try: `echo $node->filter('td.up_schedule')->eq(1)->text();`

Comment: It would help to see what it is you're filtering.

Comment: i use this line but showing The current node list is empty. invallidArgumentException

Comment: Try: `$node->filter('td')->nextAll();`

Comment: i tried this line as well but it is showing the result Schedule (MW) Drawl (MW) like but not showing their associated value. in these column it is returning the jquery functions as a code.

Comment: Try with `echo $node->filter('td')->siblings();` May be it work!

Comment: can you give full code for ->siblings();

Comment: no impact same javascript is returning

Comment: Last try: `$crawler->filter('body > td')->siblings();` and don't do this: `$crawler->filter('body')->each(function ($node) {
      echo "<pre>";
      //var_dump($node->text());
      echo $node->filter('td')->eq(0)->text();
       echo $node->filter('td.up_schedule')->text();
       echo $node->filter('td')->eq(2)->text();

    });`

Comment: Try $crawler->filter('body > td')->siblings(); showing The current node list is empty.

Comment: See this link: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html